# What's the difference between 眼熟 and 面熟?

Tags: vocabulary

I've always assumed that you use 面熟 for people because they have a face (面). However, I recently heard a native speaker use 眼熟 about a person.

Are the two phrases fully interchangeable?

If not, what are the subtle differences (which I'm apparently missing)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are not fully interchangeable.

In 面熟/脸熟, 面/脸 are nouns for 'familiar what'. 面熟/脸熟 means 'familiar face'.

In 眼熟/耳熟, 眼/耳 are functioning as adverbs for 'how is it familiar'. 眼熟 means 'looks familiar', 耳熟 means 'sounds familiar'.

As a result, 面熟/脸熟 are mostly used for people, 眼熟/耳熟 can be used on anything that you can look at or listen to. For a familiar face, either one is fine.

Answer (score 0):

They can be used interchangeably. If there has to be some subtle differences, 眼, eye, we see by eyes; when we look at people, we usually first look at their faces. 面.thus 面熟 in particular refers to 'people are familiar'. NS.X explains the differences well.

Comment: again question easily answered by looking up iciba：
all １０ sample sentences for 面熟 are about people looking familiar， whereas 眼熟  has ３ sample sentences about rooms，handwriting ，or pieces of ivory， besides ７ about people looking familiar。

Comment: @S.Rhee - All that tells me is that both could be used in _similar_ contexts. It doesn't actually answer my question (about whether there are subtle differences / reasons to prefer one over the other).

Comment: one context is all people，the other context is objects as well as people